# Solving MaxDouble Slice Kadane's Algorithm Variation

Tags: arrays, algorithm, kadanes-algorithm

I was trying to sharpen my skills by solving the Codality problems. I reached this one: https://codility.com/programmers/lessons/9-maximum_slice_problem/max_double_slice_sum/

I actually theoretically understand the solution:

1. Use Kadane's Algorithm on the array and store the sum at every index.
2. Reverse the array and do the same.
3. Find a point where the sum of both is max by looping over both result sets one at a time.
4. The max is the max double slice.

My question is not so much about how to solve the problem. My question is about how does one imagine that this will be way in which this problem can be solved. There are at-least 3 different concepts that need to be made use of:

1. The understanding that if all elements in the array are positive, or negative it is a different case than when there are some positive and negative elements in the array.
2. Kadane's Algorithm
3. Going over the array forward and reversed.

Despite all of this, Codality has tagged this problem as "Painless".

My questions is am I missing something? It seems hard that I would be able to solve this problem without knowing some of these concepts.

Is there a technique where I can start from scratch and very basic concepts and work my way up to the concepts required to solve this problem. Or is it that I am expected to know these concepts before even starting the problem?

How can I prepare my self to solve such problems where I don't know the required concepts in the future?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are overthinking the problem, that's why you find it more difficult than it is:

> The understanding that if all elements in the array are positive, or negative it is a different case than when there are some positive and negative elements in the array.

It doesn't have to be a different case. You might be able to come up with an algorithm that doesn't care about this distinction and works anyway.

You don't need to start by understanding this distinction, so don't think about it until or even if you have to.

> Kadane's Algorithm

Don't think of an algorithm, think of what the problem requires. Usually that 10+ paragraph problem statement can be expressed in much less.

So let's see how we can simplify the problem statement.

It first defines a slice as a triplet `(x, y, z)`. It's defined at the sum of elements starting at `x+1`, ending at `z-1` and not containing `y`.

Then it asks for the maximum sum slice. If we need the maximum slice, do we need `x` and `z` in the definition? We might as well let it start and end anywhere as long as it gets us the maximum sum, no?

So redefine a slice as a subset of the array that starts anywhere, goes up to some `y-1`, continues from `y+1` and ends anywhere. Much simpler, isn't it?

Now you need the maximum such slice.

Now you might be thinking that you need, for each `y`, the maximum sum subarray that starts at `y+1` and the maximum sum subarray that ends at `y-1`. If you can find these, you can update a global max for each `y`.

So how do you do this? This should now point you towards Kadane's algorithm, which does half of what you want: it computes the maximum sum subarray ending at some `x`. So if you compute it from both sides, for each `y`, you just have to find:

```
kadane(y - 1) + kadane_reverse(y + 1)
```

And compare with a global max.

No special cases for negatives and positives. No thinking "Kadane's!" as soon as you see the problem.

The idea is to simplify the requirement as much as possible without changing its meaning. Then you use your algorithmic and deductive skills to reach a solution. These skills are honed with time and experience.

Comment: Thanks. You said, "It first defines a slice as a triplet (x, y, z). It's defined at the sum of  elements starting at x+1, ending at z-1 and not containing y."

Now, if the array is 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 then the max sub array is the whole array. And the max sub array reversed is also the whole array. So it does not factor in the above requirement of dropping the first and last element. (Or am I not understanding something correctly?)

Is this not a special case that the general algo will not handle?

Comment: @KhojBadami I don't see how. What is the answer for that example when applying the original definition and my simplified definition, according to you? Either way, even if it gets that wrong somehow, the point is that now you have a solution that mostly works, give or take some edge cases. Now you can focus on how to handle those edge cases: either by identifying and treating them separately, or by adapting your solution to be able to handle them. Don't start developing a solution by starting from the edge cases.

Comment: Okay, "Don't start developing a solution by starting from the edge cases.". This is what I think is my problem. As you said originally I am making the question more complicated than it needs to be. Need to simplify as you have explained. Thank you.